# Errors when trying to display relational data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been following the Laracasts Project-Flyer and have come to an end of the current videos in the series. I have decided to go off and expand on the app myself.

I'm trying to display the latest 3 flyers ( or in my case, classifieds) on the home page, along with an image.

I have been able to pull the last 3 entries and display them fine on the home page, but I've been trying to follow the same approach of displaying the images on the classified page, for the images for each classified on the home page.

Here is my code I have used.

Classified Model snippet:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class classified extends Model
{

...

public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\classified_photo');
}

...

public static function getLatestClassifeds()
{   
    return DB::table('classifieds')
    ->select('ad_title','description')
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
}

...
```

Home Page Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\classifiedRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\classified;
use App\classified_photo;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $classifieds = classified::getLatestClassifeds();

        return view('pages.home', compact('classifieds'));
    }
}
```

Home View:

```
@foreach($classifieds as $classified)
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @if($classified->photos)
                @foreach($classified->photos as $photo)
                    <img src="/{{$photo->thumbnail_path}}" class="img-responsive">
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="classified-desc">
                <h2>{{$classified->ad_title}}</h2>
                <p>{{$classified->description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This code returns this error when I try to view the home page:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$photos (View: /var/www/html/barrys-bikes.dev/resources/views/pages/home.blade.php)
```

As I say, displaying the 3 classifieds works fine, its just this issue with trying to then pull an image for each one.

Comment: What should be in `->photos` object? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Just edited the post to now include the photos() function which is situated in the classified model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is, because you using `DB::table()...` instead of Eloquent ORM. Do something like this:

```
public static function getLatestClassifeds()
{   
    return self::orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->take(3)->get(['ad_title', 'description']);
}
```

Comment: Gave that a go, now I'm getting this error : Using $this when not in object context

Comment: @Mike.Linford Sorry, I forgot about that. Updated answer, I checked them and everything works fine.

Comment: Brilliant, that's fixed that. Thanks. I am getting another issue however. what would be the best way to obtain the first image that belongs to a classified? I'm currently pulling in all images and then in my view, I'm jsut displaying the first key in the array. I feel like this isn't right. I'm also running into the issue of display a place holder image if a user has not yet uploaded an image for the classified to be shown on the home page. How can I check to see if a classified does not have an image, and if it doesn't, display something else?